# Filter( ) function takes function with two inputs

Tags: python, python-2.7, filter

I'm trying to write a filter function that pass me a list of dictionary words that can be formed by letters from a rack.

```
def test(Rack, word):
"""test whether a string can be formed with the letters in the Rack."""
if word == "" or Rack == []:
    return True
elif word[0] in Rack:
    return True and test(Rack, word[1:])
else:
    return False
```

Then my map function will need the test function.

```
def stringsInDic(Rack, dictionary):
    return filter(test(Rack, dictionary) == True, dictionary)
```

But as we can see, the second input of filter should be an element from the dictionary, which is what filter puts in. So I'm not sure how to write the second argument in test.

Please help!!! Thanks!

Comment: Your test can be written more succinctly as `not rack or all(char in rack for char in word)`

Comment: Making a word finder for Scrabble, eh? ;-) If so, your function needs some more work. `test(["n", "o"], "noon")` returns `True`, but you definitely can't spell "noon" with just two tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
def stringsInDic(Rack, dictionary):
    func = functools.partial(test, Rack)
    return filter(func, dictionary)
```

`partial` allows you to create a sort of place-holder function, which you can add more arguments to later. So `func` becomes `test(Rack, ...)`. If you were to later call `func(something)`, You'd really be executing `test(Rack, something)`.